# How do I replace the very last character in a text area field?

Tags: javascript

For examples

test1, test2, test3, test4,

How do I replace the very last character (comma) with a period?

Comment: do you want to replace it when a certain event happens e.g. when the text area loses focus?

Comment: A 'period' is what USAns call a full stop.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This removes the trailing comma if any and adds a period:

```
textarea.value = textarea.value.replace(/,$/, "") + ".";
```

`textarea.value` is a string which has a `replace` method. As first argument, a regular expression is given (characterized by a single leading `/`) which matches a comma on the end (`$`). The match (if any) is replaced by nothing (removed) and a period is appended.

Beware that this code resets the scrolling (at least in Firefox) and the cursor position.

Another snippet that removed a traling comma, but which does not add a period if there is no trailing comma:

```
textarea.value = textarea.value.replace(/,$/, ".");
```

Comment: Which way is faster? `.replace()` with regex or `.slice(0, -1)`?

Comment: @Ifch0o1 My gut says that slice is faster because the logic should be must simpler compared to search-and-replace code. You can measure it, but I think it would be micro-optimization...

Comment: Excellent stuff. Cheers!

Answer (score 9):

You can use `.slice()` to remove the last character, then just concatenate the  period.

```
var ta = document.getElementById('mytextarea');

ta.value = (ta.value.slice(0,-1) + '.');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var yourTextarea = document.getElementById('textareaId'); // get your textarea element
var val = yourTextarea.value; // get text, written in textarea
val = val.slice(0,-1); // remove last char
val += charToReplace; // add char, that you want to be placed instead of comma
yourTextarea.value = str; // set just edited text into textarea
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check for a comma at the end and then replace it:

```
if (myString.substr(myString.length - 1, 1) == ',') {
  myString = myString.substr(0, myString.length - 1) + '.';
}
```

Or you can blindly replace it:

```
  myString = myString.substr(0, myString.length - 1) + '.';
```

Comment: `myString.charAt(myString.length - 1)` does the same as the `substr` in your `if`

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].innerHTML.substr(0, document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].innerHTML.length - 1)
```

Comment: A textarea is identical to `<input>` elements in the sense that it's a form element. Therefore, it has a `value` property which is preferred over `innerHTML`.

Comment: `<textarea>` is indeed not `<input>`, but it has a `value` property and even `type` (which is "textarea")

Comment: @Lekensteyn is correct. This will only be effective on the original content. If the value of the `textarea` has been updated, you'd need to use its `.value` property instead of `.innerHTML`. Additionally 3 separate DOM selections to accomplish one task is not good form. Sorry, but this really isn't a good overall solution. -1